# Can I use AirportExpress model A1088 to connect to TimeCapsule for AirTunes only?

Tags: airport, time-capsule, airtunes

I have a home wireless setup running on TimeCapsule (network on n). I would love to have AirTunes and it happens that a friend of mine can give me an old AirportExpress base station. However, this being an old b/g version (model A1088) I am not sure whether I can use it.

I don't need to extend my wireless, I can connect AiportExpress with TimeCapsule using the cable and I only want to use AE for AirTunes (to connect to my stereo), nothing else. Can I do it?

thanks!
yot

Answer (score 1):

Simple and direct answer is yes if you plan to use the ethernet connection. Beware that you will need to download the old configuration utility [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1536) to change the settings on this model.